# Get bootstrap dateTimePicker value in code behind asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, webforms

I have the following `dateTimePicker` in my Asp.net project which works fine. I now need to access the value of the selected date and time from my code behind.

```
<label for="couponDatetimepickerEnd">Coupon Valid To</label>
<br/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group date" id="couponDatetimepickerEnd" runat="server">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" />
        <span class="input-group-addon">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my JavaScript code to launch the `dateTimePicker`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#couponDatetimepickerEnd').datetimepicker({
      sideBySide: true
    });
  });

  function getEndDate() {
    return $('#couponDatetimepickerEnd').val()
  };
</script>
```

As you can see I've added another function `getEndDate()` which I hoped would get the value and return it to my code behind when called.

Here is my code behind where I'm trying to get the value. As you can see I've tried two different ways to access the values of my dateTimePickers, neither works.

```
protected void setCouponOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var offerStartString = ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
        this, 
        this.GetType(), 
        "startDate", 
        "getStartDate();", 
        true);

    var offerEndString = ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
        this, 
        this.GetType(), 
        "endDate", 
        "getEndDate();", 
        true);

    //var offerStartString = Page.Request.Form["couponDatetimepickerStart"];
    //var offerEndString = Page.Request.Form["couponDatetimepickerEnd"];
    DateTime offerStart = DateTime.Parse(offerStartString);
    DateTime offerEnd = DateTime.Parse(offerEndString);
}
```

Comment: I've tidied up your code and English. Making sure your question is well formatted helps us help you.

Comment: Cheers and sorry about that. I wrote it out in a hurry and should have read  back over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the value on server side like this - the code is being run on the client and no way to send it to the server.

You can make the `input` to be `runat="server"` and access the value via `Id` of the control, or examine the `Request` collection during request.

Comment: I have tired adding the runat=server like this

<div class="input-group date" id="couponDatetimepickerEnd" runat="server">

And then in the code behind how do i access the date that has been input? 

 var offerStartString = couponDatetimepickerEnd.[what here]

There is no .Text or .Value properties available

Comment: @user3753146 you can't acces the datepicker if you done runat for the div.

Comment: As VMAtm said, that won't work.  Add it to the datePicker control itself and not the block element.  Then utilise your On_Click event.